# Many one to many into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, one-to-many

I have a view in SQL Server 2008 R2 that looks like the 'table' below.

I'd like to have a 'crosstab' view or stored procedure to have the results as described below. The view is comprised of three tables Main --- to many Props --- to many lineitems

```
Mainname | Prop | lineitems
---------+------+------------
Smith    | P1   | cheese  
Smith    | P1   | tires  
Smith    | P1   | baseballs  
Smith    | P2   | gel  
Smith    | P3   | windows  
Smith    | P3   | guitar  
Jones    | T4   | shoes  
Lane     | Q1   | cushion  
Lane     | Q2   | dirt
```

I need to get it to look like this:

```
Mainname | Prop1 | lineitems1 | lineitems2 | lineitems3 | Prop2 | lineitems1 | Prop3 | lineitems1 | lineitems2
---------+-------+------------+------------+------------+-------+------------+-------+------------+-----------
Smith    | P1    | cheese     | tires      | baseballs  | P2    | gel        | P3    | windows    | guitar  
Jones    | T4    | shoes  
Lane     | P5    | cushion    | <null>     | <null>     | P6    | dirt
```

[image: Image example of above]

Comment: You want to make a **PIVOT**. Luckily, SQL Server have advanced features for that, and there are plenty of examples on SO, do a search with PIVOT keyword

Comment: What determines that cheese is item1, tires is item2, and baseballs is item3? I can see nothing in your table that can achieve that order with an `ORDER BY` clause. `ORDER BY L_items` would place baseballs, cheese and tires in positions 1, 2, and 3 respectively (thus none woul;d be in the same place).

Comment: Jeff Moden has an excellent article on this very topic. Dynamic cross tabs. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/

Answer (score 0):

The real problem here is the table design. You have a single column representing many different things. In a relation database this is just a bad idea.

One way to method to fix the problem is called "CROSS PIVOTing". This is pseudo-SQL in the absence of consumable data, and there are assumptions involved, as per my comments:

```
WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT *,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY Prop) AS PropRN
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name], Prop ORDER BY Item) AS ItemRN
    FROM YourTable)
SELECT [Name],
       MAX(CASE WHEN PropRN = 1 THEN Prop END) AS Prop1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PropRN = 1 AND ItemRN = 1 THEN Item END) AS Prop1Item1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PropRN = 1 AND ItemRN = 2 THEN Item END) AS Prop1Item2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PropRN = 1 AND ItemRN = 3 THEN Item END) AS Prop1Item3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PropRN = 2 THEN Prop END) AS Prop2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PropRN = 2 AND ItemRN = 1 THEN Item END) AS Prop2Item1,
       ...
FROM RNs
GROUP BY [Name];
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Larnu's answer may work (I didn't try it).  the solution that works for me is this. and I added another column to the table...costs

```
declare @Count int,@Cur int
declare @Qry nvarchar(4000)
set @Cur=1

select @Count=max(t.count) from (

select proposal, count(lineitems) count from view_1 group by proposal) t

set @Qry=''

while @Cur<@Count+1
begin
set @Qry= @Qry + ',(select t.lineitems from (select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by lineitems) ROW_NUMBER, 
lineitems from view_1 where proposal = t1.proposal) t where ROW_NUMBER='+ cast(@Cur as varchar(10)) + ') as lineitem' + cast(@Cur as varchar(10))
set @Qry= @Qry + ',(select t.costs from (select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by lineitems) ROW_NUMBER, 
costs from view_1 where proposal = t1.proposal) t where ROW_NUMBER='+ cast(@Cur as varchar(10)) + ') as costs' + cast(@Cur as varchar(10))

set @Cur=@Cur+1
end

set @Qry='select distinct t1.grantname, t1.proposal ' + @Qry + ' from view_1 t1 order by 1, 2'

print @Qry
exec sp_executesql @Qry
```